# In C# Does using File.OpenRead() needs to be closed?

Tags: c#

I did not find info about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=netcore-3.1

I'm checking if the file exists so that it is ready to be used. I will open the file soon later again. And I'm wondering if it is a better practice to close it after making the check.

**Do I need to close the file after File.OpenRead()?**

```
bool DoesFileOpensAndRead(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: do you know what the `using` block does?

Comment: Probably no! I was thinking is part of using System.IO;

Comment: @AlanMattano - Read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). `using` blocks don't have anything to do with `System.IO`.

Comment: "I will open the file soon later again" - you need to realise that anything your code established about a file in the *past* may not be in any way relevant to what you may be able to do in the *future*. The file may have been deleted, overwritten, had it's permissions changed, etc. You **cannot** pre-check anything about a file and write correct code based purely on those pre-checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not NEED to close it - it will be closed automatically AT SOME POINT.

BUT: if you actually want to release the file lock that you created without waiting possibly for the next computer restart (or, technically more correct: until someone closes the program and the OS releases the file lock) then yes, you should delete it. This is not a "need" though (same as locking your car in a parking space is not a "need" - you likely get robbed at some point, but you do not need to lock it).

Now, your code example is more funny - it does not work. Period.

Your File.OpenRead is automatically DISPOSED at the end of the function. This is what the using statement does, and using is also internally closing the file. I am just not sure what the sense is as you are not actually doing anything with the file handle. You are WAY better of to not open read but - RTFM.

> I'm checking if the file exists so that it is ready to be used.

Ah, yeah. Why not do it with the method that does that?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1

File.Exists is identical, in particular because "open it soon" is no guarantee that the file

- is still there when you use it
- CAN be opened when you use it.

Open does do some additional checks (can you actually read it, from the permissions?), but

- There is no guarantee that these permissions are in place at he time of test (note how you say "soon," not "immediately"
- The conditions may change before you open.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the `IDisposable` interface through the `using` statement, you do not need to call `Close`, `Dispose` will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Using statement you are using will dispose of it automatically

read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement for more information